# Why do I need a sub-$\sigma$-algebra in order to define the conditional expectation?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value, conditional-expectation

> Let $(\Omega, \mathfrak{A},\Bbb{P})$  be a probability space with $\mathfrak{B}\subset \mathfrak{A}$ a sub-$\sigma$-algebra. Let $X\in L^1(\Omega, \mathfrak{A},\Bbb{P})$ be a random variable. Then there exists a unique random variable $\xi$ which is $\mathfrak{B}$-measurable such that for all random variables $Z$ which are also $\mathfrak{B}$-measurable and bounded we have $$\Bbb{E}(XZ)=\Bbb{E}(\xi Z)$$ We call this $\xi$ the conditional expectation of $X$ given $\mathfrak{B}$ and denote it by $$\xi=\Bbb{E}(X|\mathfrak{B})$$

This is our definition of the conditional expectation I have read in a book. I know that there are equivalent characterizations. But now I asked myself why do I need $\mathfrak{B}$? Why can't I only work with $\mathfrak{A}$? I have also read about conditional expectation viewed as a projection, does this help to understand why we need to work with $\mathfrak{B}$ instead of $\mathfrak{A}$?

It would be nice if someone could explain this to me.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This should be clearest if you start by thinking of finite $\sigma$-algebras.

Comment: @YuvalPeres Sorry I don't get what you mean? Could you maybe explain this to me? 
Because our random variable $X:\Omega\rightarrow E$ where for example $E=\Bbb{R}$ right? But then the sigma algebra $\mathfrak{A}$ I wrote above is the sigma algebra on $\Omega$ or am I wrong?

Comment: Exactly, consider the case where $\Omega$ is finite.

Comment: @YuvalPeres but isn't $\Omega$ our universe, i.e. we have no informations about $\Omega$? 
Nevertheless when I consider $\Omega$ to be finite what does this gives me?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23600/intuition-behind-conditional-expectation would help you to understand.

Answer (score 2):

If we are not permitted to consider sub-$\sigma$-algebras, and we must take $\mathfrak B=\mathfrak A$, then the definition of conditional expectation $E(X\mid{\mathfrak A})$ is trivially satisfied by $X$ itself, which makes the concept not very interesting. The only interesting conditional expectations arise when $\mathfrak B$ is a strict sub algebra.

Example: A common problem is to evaluate the conditional expectation of random variable $X$ given the sigma-algebra generated by another random variable (or random vector) $Y$. This requires us to find $E(X \mid \sigma(Y))$, often abbreviated $E(X\mid Y)$, and answers the question: if you've observed $Y$, how does this knowledge affect what you expect the value of $X$ to be? See for example [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2205722/215011). If $Y$ is a constant random variable, or if $Y$ is independent of $X$, you can prove that $E(X\mid Y)=E(X)$, i.e., knowledge of $Y$ doesn't change what you expect $X$ to be.

Comment: Ah okey I see. But is there also like a geometric interpretation with the projection?

Comment: Yes, see for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2442767/215011 . In some treatments, the conditional expectation $E(X\mid \mathfrak B)$ is *defined* as the  projection onto the subspace $L^2(\Omega, \mathfrak B, P)$.